# how to wrap a script spawning multiple processes with Expect?

Tags: mercurial, passwords, expect

I'm running "hg fpull" that pulls via ssh. I'd like to feed it with the password only ones. Yes, I'm aware about ssh-keygen, but Expect would be more preferable for me.

So, here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

stty -echo
send_user "Password: "
expect_user -re "(.*)\n"
set password $expect_out(1,string)
send_user "\n"
stty echo

spawn hg fpull -u --snapfile <snapfile>
expect {
    "Password:" { send "$password\r"; exp_continue; }
}
interact
```

The problem is that "hg fpull" spawns a new process to pull from a new repository. A new process gets Expect out of the cycle...

So, how to deal with this? Is that possible at all with Expect? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Still hope to get an answer...

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, what is required is that you get the #spawn_id for your spawned process. You can then match per process (expect -i ) and close per process.

There is a nice example here:
http://wiki.tcl.tk/16158

I am not sure what you mean with the password once bit. Does this apply per "hg pull" or is it overall.

In the latter case you might want to do that in an overall expect script that then spawns childs with whom you communicate the password that is stored during runtime.

Comment: I'm passing a list of ssh paths as a snapfile. Pulling for each tree  requires me to enter a password ones again. My script works for the first tree, it sends the password, hg pulls for the tree but then it spawns a new process to pull for the next one. This makes the expect cycle finish.

So, when I call "spawn <cmd>", I then call expect {..} to catch up with the spawned process. But how to catch up with the processes spawned from the <cmd> itself?

Hope I made it clearer...

Comment: The easiest way I see at this point in time is to deal with this is to not use a snapfile, but run the command line for line thereby using the expect -i option. I am not that familiar with HG / mercurial, but I bet that should do the trick.

Comment: Well, this is an option. Thanks for your comments.